# How to secure blueprint access in Sails.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, sails.js

So I'm pretty new to Sails.js but it seems to bring a lot to the table like these blue prints,

Right now I have 2 models, `Accounts` / `Friends`

It is using association as `Accounts` has many `Friends`

On my client side I have a way to send notifications to users, one being a friends request so that works fine, it gives the user an option to accept or decline the invite

Here's the code:

```
socket.on('accounts', function(data) {
    if (data.verb === "addedTo" && data.attribute === "notifications") {
      socket.get('/notifications/' + data.addedId, function(note) {
        console.log(note);
        if (!$.isEmptyObject(note)) {
          $scope.notifications.push({
            'text': note.from_name + ' sent you a friends request',
            'id':   note.id,
            'type': note.type,
            'from_id': note.from_id
          })
          $.notify('You have a new notification', 'info');
          $scope.$digest();
        }
      })
    }
  })

$scope.accept = function(notificationId, fromId) {

}
```

When people press the Accept button, I want to add a friend for both the person that accepted the notification, and the person that sent it so that it's mutual and they're both friends with each other.

I could simply do that by making a data object and doing `socket.post` to friends for both of them, and then doing a `socket.put` to update the notification as being read and deal away with it

The only problem is, I don't want people to come in and open JS console and spam `socket.post` a million friends to people maliciously

```
var obj {
  'friend_name': 'Bill',
  'online': 1
}

socket.post('/accounts/1/friends', obj);
```

So, how can I secure this so that people accessing `post` to `/accounts/1/friends` is only people that should be accessing this?

If I'm not making sense just ask. Thanks!

Example of being spammed:

somebody opens JS console and goes

`var obj = { friend_name: 'bill', owner: 1 }; io.socket.post('/friends', obj);`

500 times now the account with `id` 1 has 500 friends named bill

Comment: Could you provide a real life example of such spam with `socket.post`. I have a problem understanding your question.

Comment: @HristoEnev added check the bottom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct me if I misunderstood something but I think your logic is wrong.

I assume Bill is also an account, but when you add only his name you don't have any connection with his account information and also can identify him only by a name. In order to have some kind of validation you will need an unique identifier of Bill. Instead of name you can add `account_id` and `owner`.

So if there are 3 accounts:

1. Chris
2. Bill
3. Joe

You will add `var obj = { account_id: 2, owner: 1 };`

So that way you can check with [policies](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/Policies) if friend with account_id and owner already exists before adding a new friend. If you have any questions about how to use policies just ask.

Anyway I think a better approach will be to have only one model and a [many to many](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/ORM/Associations/ManytoMany.html) relationship with that model alone. Account will have a many to many relationship with itself through a third table that Sails will create (that will be your friends table). That way in the new table you will have two columns that will contain account ids. If let's say on the first row you have ids 1 and 2, that means Chris and Bill are both friends and you can think of some logic to make sure the rows are always unique so that you don't have problem with spam. Just for the record I haven't done many to many relationship with one model so you have to figure it out how it's done.